# Is this motor suitable for my project?

Tags: motor, dc

i have a project which have 4 18volt DC motors, each motor rotate a screw which is 8mm and pitch 1.25mm and 200mm length vertically, load connected via nut in screw, every motor has 3.5 KG load and total load 14 KG.
in my calculation every motor torque 50 oz-in and im selected a motor kindly guide me this motor is best for this or not, and if any other motor under 10-12$

Model: RS-775WC

Operation Voltage 6-18 V

No load: 21000rpm, 2.80A,

At max Efficiency: 1850rpm, 20.9A, Torque=1560 g.cm, o/p=296W

Stall: Torque=13201 g.cm, 156A

Thank you, sorry for bad english

Comment: So you don't mind if it takes three days to get from one mechanical limit to the other?

Comment: @Andyaka - Oh, come on, a nominal 5 seconds isn't bad. I'd worry more about providing a nominal 84 amps/1200 watts.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm trying to tease out relevant info from the OP. Does it say 5 seconds somewhere or maybe I've misinterpreted you?

Comment: @Andyaka - using a 1.25 mm pitch screw and 200 mm travel gives 160 revolutions for full travel. Using the "nominal" 1850 rpm gives 5.19 seconds. Although it's true that raising 14 kg 200 mm only takes 27.4 J, so the motor will run a great deal faster than 1850 rpm, and travel time will be much less.

Comment: There is a major discrepancy in these specs : if the no load speed is 21000 rpm the max efficiency speed is probably 18500rpm. It certainly cannot be 1850, unless no-load speed was supposed to be 2100rpm.  Assuming 1560g.cm means 0.156Nm, (why do people insist on expressing torque as mass * distance when it's force * distance?) this torque * 1850rpm would be about 30W. Somebody needs to check the data sheet.

Comment: Everything was going well until oz-in crept in

Comment: actually its question by another for me, so i was surprised thats to much rpm so just asked some experts. u all know the scenario please suggest me the motor for my requirements in 24 VDC supply.

Comment: kindly suggest me the motor plz